# Adding LinearLayout to ListView using an adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to create a `ListView` where each entry in the list consists of a `LinearLayout`. I have an `ArrayList` that I have defined here:

`ArrayList<LinearLayout> menuList;`.

Later in my code, I define

`LinearLayout dailyMenuLayout = new LinearLayout(ReturnMenus.this);`, and every time I complete a layout to be added to the ListView, I use `menuList.add(DailyMenuList)`

The adapter that I have been trying to use is as follows -- but it crashes the app every time that it is triggered.

`ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>(ReturnMenus.this, R.id.linear_layout_item, menuList);
 myListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

And this is the XML for the single row in the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody show me how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of using this kind of layout? Normally we used layouts to arrange views(Buttons, TextView etc.).

Comment: I want to layout groups of TextViews in a ListView, where each entry in the ListView might have a different number of TextViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like following layout for the row layout in your list  rather than you current layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here if you do not know exactly how many textView that you are going to use, use maximum number of TextView that using in your application. Then in your adapter class inside getView() you can get those TextView. If some rows not going to use all of these textViews then  set them invisible as like this:

```
TextView txtView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
txtView3.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Following tutorial helps you to create the listView.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You should bind data to adapter,such as strings,not the layout.

To see how to use ListView and Adapter,please check the demo project in *your-android-sdk-dir\samples\android-XX\ApiDemos*.